# remove borders of Accordion in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is pic of nav-list class:

[image: screenshot]

I want to make a dropdown with accordion. To do this, I want to remove the borders.

I have tried the following, but its not working:

```css
.accordion, .accordion * {
    border:none;
}
```

Here's my html code:

```
<div class="span3">
    <ul class="nav nav-list">

        <li><a href="#">At least 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">At least 3</a></li>
        <li class="nav-header">Search by Hourly rate</li>
        <li><a href="#">dfa</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="accordion" id="ac2">
        <div class="accordion-group">
            <div class="accordion-heading">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#ac2" href="#cone">
                    item #1
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="cone" class="accordion-body collapse">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                    adfadf<br />dafa
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-group">
            <div class="accordion-heading">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#ac2" href="#ctwo">
                    item #2
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="ctwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                    what is ad
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions to make dropdowns like accordion?

Comment: You should have the html from the view displaying as well.  That way we can identify the DOM objects in question and which ones lie within the other.

Comment: Did you have a border initially in the accordion class in the css file? Maybe it's inherited from a parent. Did you inspect the element with Firebug or similar tool?

Comment: No all css related to accordion is mentioned in question.

Comment: Is this for Bootstrap 2 or 3?  `.span3` is from version 2

Comment: This can't be Bootstrap 3 as the screenshot above wouldn't look like that.

Comment: I think its B3. I have downloaded it today from http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/index.html . Also .col-xs-# is not working on it that's why i have used .span#

Comment: Bootstrap's current version is v3.2.0 http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download  You've just shared v2.3.2 as your source.  That is version 2.

Comment: for grid system .span# is used in v3.2.0 ?

Comment: Is there separate description of v3.2.0 as there is for v2.3.2 i.e, getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/index.html

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. I have found what i was looking for...

Comment: The getbootstrap.com pages without a version number will be the latest version.

Answer (score 2):

Theo border is on the `accordion-group` class, that is Bootstrap 2 (and likely 3) kindly adding that for you. Fix it like this:

```
.accordion-group {
  border: none;
}
```

Comment: There is no submit button on bootply. How to apply css ?

Comment: Press the `Run` link at top of the page.

Answer (score 2):

It was not working because i was using Bootstrap v 2.3.2
It worked properly when i upgraded it to Bootstrap v 3.2.0